# I want to calculate the total price of a customer's purchase from my code in django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am trying to calculate the total price of items when a user types in the rate and quantity of an item purchased, but I'm getting this error: "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'"
My model is below; it includes where I'm performing the operation of getting the total price.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import fields
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE

# Create your models here.

class Items(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name

class Payment_Method(models.Model):
    payed_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payed_by

class Daily_Sales(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_purchased = models.ManyToManyField(Items)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_method = models.ManyToManyField(Payment_Method)
    have_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_paid = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Daily_Sales'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.customer_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_price = self.rate * self.quantity
        super(Daily_Sales, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Thus the error; can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple'

Comment: It looks strange that your `DailySales` has a `rate` and `quantity`, since it has a many-to-many field to `Items`. This thus means that it can "span" over multiple *different* items, each with their own price, etc.

Comment: The price of an item will be provided by a user and the quantity also.

Comment: Then the system will multiply the provided rate and quantity

Comment: Please also put your serializer and view code. I think you set 'rate' and 'quantity' values for Daily_Sales object without validating it as it must be integer.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that model Daily_Sales only has 1 rate, but multiple items.  So that would imply that a customer is buying the same amount of each of several different items; I don't think that's what you want?   Assuming that you actually want each line item of the Daily_Sales to have it's own rate and item, you could create a class for the line item like this:

```
class Line_Item(models.Model):
    item_purchased = models.ForeignKey(Items, null = False, blank=False)
    rate = models.IntegerField(null = False, blank=False)

    def subtotal(self):
        return self.item_purchased * self.rate
```

Line_Item should also have a link to the Daily_Sales somehow; possibly through an order number, or if you don't use order numbers, then through the customer_name plus the date_purchased.  Then, in your Daily_Sales model total_price function, you would get the queryset of line_items matching the order number (or customer/date combination) and iterate through it adding up each of the subtotals.